# Como levar dados através do método GET?

Tags: php, mysql, get, link

Estou montando um painel para controle financeiro de uma empresa MEI (Essa empresa é minha). Estou desenvolvendo a parte dos pedidos, segue dúvida:

A questão é que já utilizo esse `GET` para buscar as páginas, como poderia adicionar a esse link para levar a ID do pedido para mostrar no outro campo?

Exemplo do Link:

```
<a href="index.php?Pagina=pag&filtro=pedido">Pedidos de Vendas</a>
```

Esse Código fica no `index` para pegar o link:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['Pagina']))
    {
        $pagina =($_GET['Pagina']);
        if(file_exists('arquivos/'.$pagina.'.php'))
        {
            @include_once("arquivos/$pagina.php");
        }
        else
        {
            @include_once("arquivos/404.php");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(file_exists('arquivos/home.php'))
        {
            @include_once("arquivos/home.php");
        }
        else
        {
            @include_once("arquivos/404.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

[image: Essa é a imagem, gostaria de quando clicar em editar , ir para a página com os imputs para salvar as alterações]

Comment: Se eu entendi o que você perguntou: basta ir separando os pares com & dessa forma `index.php?Pagina=pag&filtro=pedido&numero=37&outrocampo=ABC&detalhado=sim` - queira confirmar se a dúvida é mesmo essa, para que seja possível formalizar uma resposta. Caso não seja, queira [edit] sua pergunta e explicar um pouco melhor, por favor.

Comment: É isso mesmo! Muito obrigado ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Não ficou muito claro sua dúvida, mas se for o que entendi, vc quer adicionar o ID de um pedido ou produto ao clicar em um link.

Acredito que vc já tenha um exemplo disso no seu próprio sistema, na coluna TAREFAS cada link editar/excluir faz exatamente isso.

Talvez vc queira passar mais de um parâmetro para uma página através do GET, se for isso a regra é assim:

- Para passagem do primeiro parâmetro (variável) use ? (interrogação) como separador;
- Se existir mais parâmetros (variáveis) que deseje passar para a página utilize o & (e comercial) como separador;

Exemplo:

```
<a href="index.php?Pagina=pag&filtro=pedido&idProduto=<?php echo $idProduto ?>">Pedidos de Vendas</a>
```

Deixe mais claro sua dúvida blz...

Um abraço.

Comment: Muito obrigado, a dúvida era essa mesma, esta com dúvida sobre o &teste=id muito obrigado! Ajudou muito!!!